# Apache Airflow credentials in Openmetadata

Tags: airflow

I have successfully installed OpenMetadata on ubuntu following the guideline provided here: "https://docs.open-metadata.org/v1.0.0/quick-start/local-deployment". Then I managed to change the password for my openmetadata admin. However, when I try to change the password for my Airflow admin, Openmetadata cannot connect to it after the credentials change. How can I change my default Apache Airflow password and keep working?

I tried to find the answer to this question both on Stackoverflow and Github, but could find any answers. I tried to find the config files stored in openmetadata folder, containing Airflow credentials, but still no success.

Answer (score 1):

### 1. User creation using docker compose.

If you are using docker for Openmetadata then you need to add and change some env variables

```yaml
# In docker-compose.yml
execute-migrate-all:
  environment:
    AIRFLOW_USERNAME: ${AIRFLOW_USERNAME:-new_user}
    AIRFLOW_PASSWORD: ${AIRFLOW_PASSWORD:-new_password}
openmetadata-server:
  environment:
    AIRFLOW_USERNAME: ${AIRFLOW_USERNAME:-new_user}
    AIRFLOW_PASSWORD: ${AIRFLOW_PASSWORD:-new_password}
ingestion:
  environment:
    AIRFLOW_ADMIN_USER: ${AIRFLOW_ADMIN_USER:-new_user}
    AIRFLOW_ADMIN_PASSWORD: ${AIRFLOW_ADMIN_PASSWORD:-new_password}
```

Now do the `docker compose up -d` and start all the containers.

Go to `localhost:8080` and try to login using the new username and password that you have used in the docker-compose file.
If you get logged in then the new user is successfully created in Airflow, now just try to create a new ingestion service in Openmetadata for end-to-end check.

### 2. Manual user creation.

If the above solution doesn't work then go inside the airflow container and execute the following

```
airflow users create \
    --username <NEW_USER> \
    --firstname <FIRST_NAME> \
    --lastname <LAST_NAME> \
    --role Admin \
    --email <EMAIL> \
    --password <NEW_PASSWORD>
```

Now run this to check if the user is created or not

```
airflow users list
```

Now it should work.